# Searching through large list of ordered strings

Tags: java, android

Right now as part of my android app I have a .csv file that contains aobut 15,000 lines stored on the sd card of the phone. Every time my app launches it reads in those 15,000 lines into two parallel arrays. I do this for 3 files so in total I have 6 arrays storing 15,000 elements each. I need to search through these items quickly while maintaining order.

I'm worried if I keep the code the way it is I'm going to start running out of memory on phones and having the app crash. Would it be faster just to search through the csv file using `readline` instead of reading the entirety of each array into array lists so I don't run into memory issues? Is there a better way to do this while maintaining order?

The content on the SD card is in the following form:

```
New York, test1
New Jersey, test2
Colorado, test3
Arkansas, test4
New York, test5
etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** If you want to search using the arrays, then its best to **convert the** `array` to `List` using `Arrays.asList()` method and **then use** the `contains()` method to search for the data.

**-** The other way to do this, will be using the `SQLite DataBase`

Comment: Instead of converting the arrays to lists couldn't I just start with lists? And what are the benefits of using lists?

Comment: @Peter if you can start with the List, that would be the best, as using **Collection framework in java gives more flexibility than Array**. Well for starter i will give u the most common benefit of List, is that `we don't need to mention the size of the List when we initialize it, and can dynamically add, remove..etc from the List.`

Comment: I'm already using an ArrayList is there much of a difference? Please excuse my lack of knowledge

Comment: @Peter... Well you need to use ArrayList. When i said List i meant the implementation of List. Ok its this way.... `List` is an `interface`, which is **implemented by Concrete class** like `ArrayList`, `LinkList` and `Vector`. According to you problem ArrayList or LinkList will do just fine.

Comment: Oh okay I'm sorry for the confusion, thanks so much for the clarification

Comment: @Peter you are most welcome dear......... and remember `Its always the CURIOSITY behind the CONFUSION that leads to the CLARITY...`

Comment: An `ArrayList`, or any type of `List` for that matter, is a terrible idea for this use case.

Comment: @antew **i think you missed the opening lines of my 1st point and the whole 2nd point**

Answer (score 5):

I think a better solution would be to store them in an SQLite database and use `ORDER BY` when querying, and only query what data you need at that moment.